# Visual Studio web tests: Can a coded webtest be run through the Web Test Editor run view?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, webtest

Full disclosure, I'm new to Visual Studio Web Tests and coding for them.

I've written a webtest; coded in VB; it runs great. Our QA engineer wants to use this script for performance testing; but he wants the nice GUI that comes when you build a WebTest with the VS WebTest Editor and run it.

Is there a way to run a coded webtest through this view? He wants to be able to view each test as it runs to see which pages are having issues, but within the GUI he's used to. Alternatively, I know I could just code something that writes out to a log file; but before I go with that solution; I just wanted to see if this is possible.

Any constructive input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out. From an existing web test, right click the root node and select "Add call to web test". Then selected your custom coded web test; and will now show the custom test's results in the webtest results view.